# How to Obtain Unique Records in a Collection/Varien_Db_Select

Tags: collection

I"m gettin a collection from our database.  It contains a number of sku->sku relationships.  A single sku can repeat several times but none of the relationships are identical. How do I generate a unique amount of the first sku?

table looks something like this:

```
entity_id | first_sku | second_sku | quantity
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you need a list of unique `first_sku`s? If so, try this:

```
$collection->getSelect()->group('first_sku');
```

This appends a `GROUP BY` clause to your collection's SQL query.

To optimize your collection, try the following. This gets all of your `kit_sku`s. Note, your collection filter may be `addAttributeToSelect`, depending on the kind of model. Try `addFieldToSelect` first, though.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('path/path')->getcollection()
    ->addFieldToSelect('kit_sku')   // Select only this column
    ->getSelect()
    ->group('kit_sku');

foreach ($collection as $path) {
    $mySku = $path->getKitSku();
}
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for.  Is there anyway I can just get the first_sku without needing to load the entire object?  As of now I need to do a foreach($collection as $indivdualCollection){$invidualCollection->getData('kit_sku')}

Comment: You can select specific columns when building your collection/query to avoid loading unnecessary data in the loop. How is your `$collection` created?

Comment: right now i have: mage::getmodel('path/path')->getcollection()->getselect()->group('kit_sku);

Comment: You can optimize it slightly by restricting the columns you're selecting. Updated answer.

Comment: A slight optimization over thousands of entities quickly becomes mediocre :D  Thanks again.